# Equation of a circle problem

Tags: integration, geometry, circles, tangent-line

center at `(23,-1)` externally tangent to `x^2+y^2-34x-14y+313=0`

How do you do this if the answer is in standard form. 
P.s. I just don't know how to get the radius.

Comment: Do you mean that the required circle is touching the given circle externally?

Comment: if that's the case, would the answer will be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a circle with center $A$,$B$ and radius $r$ is:

## $(x-a)^2 + (Y-b)^2 = r^2$

The equation of the circle that you start with is $x^2 + y^2 +-34x - 14y +313 = 0$.

So you rearrange this to give $(x-17)^2 + (y-7)^2 - 289 - 49 + 313 = 0$,

which simplifies to $(x-17)^2 + (y-7)^2 = 25$.

Taking the generic equation of a circle, this shows that $r^2 = 25$, therefore radius $r= 5$.

Comment: So if the radius is 5, will it be externally tangent?

Comment: yes, the center of the circle is 17,7 and 23,-1 is definitely more than 5 units away

Comment: thank you for that. I'm just confused because the graphical representation of the exteriors of the circle do not touch with each other.

Comment: and would it be the same if the question is internally tangent?

Comment: if it were an internal tangent it would be similar, you find the radius and then show that the tangent is inside the circle and will therefore cross the circumference at two points

Comment: how would I prove that the tangent is inside the circle given only the two centers and only the radius of one?

Comment: so the answer would be (x-23)^2 + (y+1) = 225 ?